# java.lang.securityexception error in my javafx with maven

Tags: maven, javafx

please help me debug this code. I am experiencing a java.lang.securityexception once I add the dynamic reports dependency in my POM. I have tried all suggested solutions provided here to no avail.This is my POM file structure

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>re.iprocu</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoperativeERP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CoperativeERP</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>re.iprocu.coperativeerp.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- DynamicReports -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>            
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
       <!--     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.4</version>
       <configuration>
        <mainClass>re.iprocu.coperativeerp.MainApp</mainClass>

                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters> 


        </configuration>
         <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-jfxjar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>build-jar</goal>                        
            </goals>
        </execution>
                <execution>
            <id>create-native</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-native</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
         </executions>
          </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>re.iprocu.coperativeerp.MainApp</mainClass>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                          <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!--
                                    Exclude files that sign a jar
                                    (one or multiple of the dependencies).
                                    One may not repack a signed jar without
                                    this, or you will get a
                                    SecurityException at program start.
                                -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                          </filters>   

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and below is the error message i am getting once i run the program:-

```
java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/JDKMessageDigest$RIPEMD256.class
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:440)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:295)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:839)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:831)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:830)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:803)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:530)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:211)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" [INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"exc":{"msg":"Q29tbWFuZCBleGVjdXRpb24gZmFpbGVkLg=="},"mojo":{"impl":"org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo","urls":["file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/mojo\/exec-maven-plugin\/1.2.1\/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/reporting\/maven-reporting-api\/2.0.6\/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/doxia\/doxia-sink-api\/1.0-alpha-7\/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/commons-cli\/commons-cli\/1.0\/commons-cli-1.0.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/plexus\/plexus-interactivity-api\/1.0-alpha-4\/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/plexus\/plexus-utils\/2.0.5\/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Kyalo\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/commons\/commons-exec\/1.1\/commons-exec-1.1.jar"],"goal":"exec","id":"org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1","source":"CLI","execId":"default-cli"},"type":"MojoFailed"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2:45.347s
Finished at: Wed Aug 03 10:00:58 EAT 2016
Final Memory: 23M/313M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project CoperativeERP: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I will greatly appreciate if i could get any assistance

Nb: the error appears once i add the dependancy for dynamic reports.without it all is OK